# Losing network connectivity every 24 hours

Tags: windows-10, networking, dhcp

Everyday at exactly the same time, my computer loses network connectivity for about a minute. It is the only computer in the house that has this problem.  When the problematic computer loses network connection, the other computers still behave normally. So it's not the connectivity between my modem and the internet that is problematic.

My computer is running windows 10 and it is connected to my home network over wifi. My router is a Nighthawk R7000.

My guess is that this is related to the DHCP lease. Here's some information on what I observe.

First, when I boot my computer it connects to the network and gets and IP address with a lease of 24 hours:

```
PS> ipconfig /all | Select-String lease

   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 26, 2020 8:56:01 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, September 27, 2020 8:56:02 AM
```

I then use the computer for about 15 minutes and put it back to sleep (right click on Windows Icon -> Shutdown or Sign-out -> Sleep).

Next, I come back at 10:31 AM, wake up the computer and run the same command:

```
PS> ipconfig /all | Select-String lease

   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 26, 2020 8:56:01 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, September 27, 2020 10:31:46 AM
```

As you can see, the lease expiry has been moved to 10:31:46 (this is exactly the time where the computer woke up from sleep). My lease expiry has therefore been moved to cover another 24 hours.

But then, on September 27 at 8:56 AM I will lose my network connection and I will get a new value for Lease Obtained/Expired. So even though my lease is still valid until 10:31, my computer loses his ip address before the expiry of the lease.

Any idea on how I can fix this?  (excluding using a static ip address)

Answer (score 0):

> my computer loses network connectivity for about a minute. It is the
> only computer in the house that has this problem.

Run TCP/IP Reset, DNS Flush.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

Then: ipconfig /flushdns

Then: restart the computer

Now test again for the loss of connection.

Comment: If I understand correctly the command, it will reset **all** network adapters. I am a little hesitant to do such changes that affects my 5 network adapters (tap, wsl, hyper-v, ethernet, wi-fi) and that could cause undesired side effect. Is there a way to apply the command to a single network adapter?

Comment: TCP/IP underlies all physical connections and does not hurt to do or have side effects.  If you specifically modified some connections, you may need to go back to set. But in my experience, running the reset command does not affect virtual setups. I have done the reset on my own machine to reset wireless. Virtual connectors were not affected.